# Regex - number from string which is not 1

Tags: php, regex

Need a regex to get numbers of pages in the thread:

example url : traidnt.net/vb/f25

i tried this :

```
'~<td class="vbmenu_control" style="font-weight:normal">.*([2-9]{1}|[0-9]{2,}).*</td>~isU'
```

but it wont work.

Thanking you

Comment: And what have you done so far and what is your problem.

Comment: @heldt - i see a culture building up about asking this sort of question. this is what i tried (.*([0-9]*)) but wont work if there is something after the number

Comment: I know this isn't what you want so I'm not posting it as an answer, but consider a perhaps simpler alternative: match all numbers in your regex, then special case/exclude 1 in the code. It may end up being more readable in the future.

Comment: @EduardoIvanec please consider this may match the wrong number without notice someday because of layout changes in the target page. being more precise in regex is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/.*?([0-9]{2,}|[2-9]{1}).*/s
```

matches a one-digit number > 1 or any multi-digit number.

please note that this does not match correctly when: "page 1 of 1 pages"

if the string is fixed, you better go with:

```
/page \d+ of (\d+) pages/is
```

or if the string is not absolutely fixed but you want the second number from the string you may use:

```
/\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)\D*/s
```

and use the second sub-match. (will also match correctly when "page 1 of 1 pages".

Comment: i need to extract the total number of pages in the thread, still not getting it right. I tried this : '~<td class="vbmenu_control" style="font-weight:normal">.*([2-9]{1}|[0-9]{2,}).*</td>~isU'   url: http://www.traidnt.net/vb/f25/

Comment: the problem was the greediness and regex order, i fixed that. try: '~<td class="vbmenu_control" style="font-weight:normal">.*?([0-9]{2,}|[2-9]{1}).*</td>~is'

Comment: works very well for me, i tried it with your page. did you remove the U modifier?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\d+` to match numbers, and a negative assertion `(?!...)` to exclude something. Often you need some anchors around to make it work reliably, here word boundaries:

```
/\b(?!1\b)\d+\b/
```

Comment: please note that this does not match correctly when: "page 1 of 1 pages"

Comment: Yours might indeed be the better approach. (Be conrete instead of relying on featuritis.)

Comment: i need to extract the total number of pages in the thread, still not getting it right. I tried this : '~<td class="vbmenu_control" style="font-weight:normal">\b(?!1\b)\d+\b</td>~isU'   url: http://www.traidnt.net/vb/f25/

Answer (score 0):

This will find all digits, which are not one:

```
/[^\D1]/
```

Comment: Presumably the OP wants to match the number 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str="page 1 of 200 pages";
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/page (\d+) of (\d+)/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[2];
}
?>
```

for the updated question:

```
$url="traidnt.net/vb/f25";
$matches1 = array();
if (preg_match('/f(\d+)/', $url, $matches1)) {
    echo $matches1[1]; 
}
?>
```